# how to find out what recipe failed

Tags: yocto, petalinux

I'm building a Xilinx image for an FPGA with Yocto. I'm somewhat new to Yocto. One of the recipes failed. From the output I can't figure out which one. Unfortunately I can't paste the log. For some reason `stackoverflow` won't allow me to do it.

Answer (score 2):

for first of all during building Yocto provides You only last few lines of execution of failed task, for more information You are always gets information which recipe was failed, location to recipe and location to error log file from the task execution - [how to view logs from failed tasks](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-viewing-logs-from-failed-tasks).
Even that in summary output at the end of whole build, there is information how many errors, warnings You have with path to recipes and information which function was failed.

Comment: FWIW: bitbake is the name of the tool used to do the build. Yocto Project just helps provide these tools.